# Have any historical texts identified whether a reincarnated soul's true identity can be identified?

Tags: history, consciousness, reincarnation, scripture, soul

If reincarnation were true, in that a soul takes on different human bodies across several different lives during that soul's existence, have philosophers, theologists, scholars or any scriptures ever indicated whether one of those lives is the true identity of that soul? Or is it implicitly always assumed that the first life or incarnation of that soul is its true identity?

Comment: I suggest that you can post this exact same question on [hinduism.se] SE too. You may get different answers there, compared to what you may get here.

Comment: Looking forward to the answers here. Judaism SE would be even more exciting.

Comment: I think this question is off-topic here because Buddhism does not have a concept of "reincarnated soul"... Or maybe that could be an answer, @user610620 what do you think?

Comment: @StopPutinStopWar The doctrine of someone like HH the Dalai Lama looks like the concept of "reincarnated soul", doesn't it? But I don't at all understand the idea that the "true identity" is either the first life or a specific life: if "reincarnation" means something I'd expect it to mean all incarnations are of the same identity. Like looking at a flock of sheep and saying, "they're all sheep" and then someone asks, "which one is the true sheep?", isn't it a nonsensical question.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow about HH etc., but sounds like we want to keep this question open, okay 

Comment: Identity and pronouns are of utmost importance to human communication. If we refer to a being by all 5 lives and names they lived, it would be a communication hodge-podge, kind of nonsensical, whereas you refer to that being by its most popular form or identity, it becomes more coherent and recognizable conceptually. So this is a bit of a philosophical question, but asking to draw from verified sources from law and scripture, from whatever civilization, regarding the "rules" of reincarnation. Out of all the lives that a soul lives, which of those lives is the soul's true or primary identity?

Comment: There's [classic doctrine here](https://suttacentral.net/mil3.1.1/en/tw_rhysdavids) that "there is no permanent individuality" and that a name of designation refers to a set of aggregates (a co-exience of various parts). That makes the question hard to answer. Within Buddhism [the word 'soul'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%80tman_(Buddhism)) is used in the context of the doctrine of "non-self" (and not the doctrine of "self"). The idea of a "soul" and a "true identity" sounds non-Buddhist -- so perhaps this question can't be answered (or can only be answer "no")?

Comment: For more about "reincarnation" in Buddhism see for example [answers to this topic](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/3420/254)

Comment: Based on the subject of that other post, is reincarnation a capability of every soul or Buddhist? Which souls reincarnate or not reincarnate and why (not)?

Comment: Maybe you'll find these answers lucid: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/157/254 and https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/10113/254 and https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/58/254

Comment: So Buddhism favors the idea of rebirth, rather than reincarnation where a soul takes a body as a vessel. Feel that all ideations of reincarnation though, in any religion, implies rebirth, that is, the soul re-starting its existence in a completely new body. Never possessing an existing body.

Comment: I think that Buddhism teaches that there are many births, and not that there's an identifiable soul that's constant (the same soul) from one birth to another. Except perhaps to say that everybody is the same.

Answer (score 3):

I can't offer you the Jewish [yarmulke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yarmulke), but I can try to explain the Buddhist [Yamaka](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.85/en/bodhi). The [Yamaka Sutta](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.85/en/bodhi) is one of the texts you can read. There are more in [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/45337/471). Another one is the [Vina Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn35/sn35.205.than.html).

Let's take the example of someone called George, whose mother has now passed away.

George knew his mother since he was a child. Then she was young and energetic.

As she grew older, her body and appearance changed. She then has wrinkles and white hair. She had trouble walking long distances because her legs weren't what they used to be. Her outlook of life and her opinions have changed. But she's still his mother.

Then in her very old age, George's mother became senile, experiencing dementia. Now she could not recognize George anymore. Her personality had changed drastically. Even George couldn't recognize her personality anymore. But she still looks like his mother and George hopes that "she is in there somewhere".

Then one day she died. George looked at his mother's dead body and cried, "Mother, why have you left me?" Although the body is there, he thinks his mother has left him. Why is this the case? Does he think his mother is not the body? Then what does he think his mother really is?

When they had a funeral service for his mother, George looked at his mother's body in the casket, and said "Goodbye Mother, I love you." So, now he thinks the body is the mother?

Long after the funeral, he reflected that when she became senile, it was like she wasn't there anymore. George thought, "Mother really left me a long time ago."

Later, after a year, he has a new daughter born to him, who looks and behaves a bit like his deceased mother. George wonders, "could my mother have been reborn again to be my new daughter?"

So, who really was his mother? Was she the form (body)?  Was she the feelings (sensations)? Was she the perceptions (including memory)? Was she the consciousness? Was she the mental formations (including personality)?

Or was she none of these? Or all of these in combination?

If you remove each of these one by one and examine it, would you find the mother?

What was her true identity?

Form, feelings, perception, consciousness and mental formations - these five aggregates are all impermanent (*anicca*), unstable and unreliable.

It's just like the case in the [Vina Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn35/sn35.205.than.html) where the king broke a lute into its constituent parts to find the melodious music that it produced. He couldn't find it.

Even in this very life, it's hard to pin down exactly the true identity or the true self. In this case, how would it be possible to pin down exactly the true identity or true self across multiple lives?

The Buddha taught that "all phenomena is not self" (*sabbe dhamma anatta*). If you look for the true identity or true self, you will find that there is none.

Also, please read [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/45337/471), [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/25302/471) and [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/39742/471).